# How to cure Tinymce editor from inspecting by browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tinymce

This is how I am adding TinyMCE editor to my web page.

```
<textarea style="resize: none;width: 0px;height: 0px;" rows="1" class="tinymce" id="tiny" name="paragraph"></textarea>
```

I am using textarea HTML tag to call TinyMCE.

But, it is being hacked by changing `style="resize: none;width: 0px;height: 0px;" rows="1"` from browser's inspect editors.

Comment: why would anyone hack a TinyMCE editor's size?

Comment: To hide TinyMCE and show textarea. From that text area  they will able to insert other codes.

Answer (score 0):

i recommand you [CK Editor](http://CkEditor.com) is responsive and better than Tiny MCE... I stopped use tiny becose of her limits...

> > Don't remember to confirm this if it help you.